# Display a popup message or a view, depending on model validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Imagine a webshop with several steps (views) during checkout. When the customer presses the 'next' button, the corresponding 'Action' method is called. In that method some validation is done, checking if the customer is free to proceed, or if there's something wrong with the order. Depending of the validation result, I'd like one of two things to happen:

A) The next view is generated and displayed.

B) The customer stays in the current page, but a modal dialog pops up, containing an error message.

I've tried several approaches found around the web, but nothing has worked so far. The last thing I tried was using AJAX, but I've actually got no clue if this is the right approach.

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 
        return View();
    }
    // If not valid
    return errorMessage          
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/SomeAction",
            async: true,
            success: function (result) {
                if (!result.success) {
                    alert(result.error);
                }
                // Else display view
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display a partial view in a modal pop up? If so, you could use the JQuery AJAX method as you've already done but combine it with a JQuery pop up/lightbox plugin to display the resulting HTML.

So, in your code where "/Home/SomeAction" is the PartialView for your pop up return a "PartialView" from your Controller and when you receive the HTML back in the JQuery "success:" event, maybe use (for example) "Jquery Colorbox" to display it (see here: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

Comment: Not quite. If the model is valid, I'd like to display some view connected to that action, but if it's not, I'd like to stay in the current view and display a popup box containing some error message from the model validation.

Comment: Ah I see, sounds like you maybe need to extend the Jquery Unobtrusive validation a little then to allow you to display pop up errors if the standard on-screen errors aren't enough

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say how do you want to achieve such workflow but one thing that comes to my mind is returning values with ie. error in TempData store and doing proper redirection to next step or if validation fails to the same step.

For simple model like this:

```
public class Cart
{
    [Required]
    public string Item { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Some code example for controller could look like this:

```
public class CartController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Cart/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Cart model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            return RedirectToAction("Step1");

        TempData["Error"] = "Validation failed";
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Step1()
    {
        // add more logic, steps etc
        return View();
    }
}
```

On view side:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     <fieldset>
       <p>
            <label for="Id">Item:</label>
            @Html.TextBox("Item") 
            @Html.ValidationMessage("Item", "*")
            @Html.Editor("Quantity")
       </p> 
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

@if (TempData["Error"] != null)
{
    <p>Please fix all errors!</p>
}
```

I would probably embeed this into view master page ie. only for those steps.

Edit: Changed some code added more real-world example :-)
Btw. keep in mind using such mechanism you'll get validation from MVC framework for free so you'll get your fields highlighted if needed. You can as well pass this model later on to other steps if needed. Overall here's nice starting guide for validation: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model

If you would like to go AJAX way then you could use something like this:

```
$.post("@Url.Action("Index")", values, function(data) {
    // add logic for loading next page or error
});
```

where values object you'll have to construct yourself with proper structure.

Good luck!

Comment: What would be the usual workflow in a scenario like this? If this was just C#/.NET, I'd have no issues, but throw in some JavaScript and HTML and I'm totally lost. If I'd go back to the same step, wouldn't this be visible to the user, like the view reloading? In case of an error, I'd like to stay in the same view without anything happening but an error popping up.

Comment: I modified example a bit for you.

Comment: return View() in Index() would reload the page, right? Would it be ok to return a script showing an error box, or is that considered bad practice?

Comment: If you're inside Index() that mean there is already some request to server, returning View instructs MVC to generate and return html to client. You can return javascript with JavaScriptResult - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.javascriptresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

No need for ajax to check a form, why not just a few lines of javascript? Like "On click, if the 'e-mail' input field is empty, throw an alert" etc. There are many form validation plug-ins out there, like [jQuery inline form validation](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/), just google it.

See : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: The model validation in this case is a bit more complex and I don't want it to leak into the view.

Comment: Ah. that's some info I didn't have before